# Positioning view

Tags: android, listview, position

I got a question:
I have a list view and a custon view positioned over it in AbsoluteLayout. When i scroll the list up - onScroll i move my view up so it goes off screen. When I scroll down it shows again. But on a device I can move list down even if I'm at the beggining of it and then it bounces back to normal position and I can NOT get the distance beetween the upper border of first list element and the upper border of activity window. Can anyone help me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use AbsoluteLayout. It is deprecated. Try the same using a Linear / RelativeLayout, I think the problem will be fixed then.